# Xamarin Forms: Ios Project not launching

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

wsHi I am developing an app using xamarin forms. My ios project was working fine but few days back it has stopped launching it.

It is saying -

```
Error: error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/project.iOS/58c9dca0bc9f1c5ed37d1e8652672fb2/bin/iPhone/Debug/project.iOS.app' on the device 'My iPad': Object reference not set to an instance of an object. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.
```

Can anyone tell me why is this coming???

I have tried running every old backup of mine. but same issue is coming.

This is my AppDelegate.cs

```
 [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
            MR.Gestures.iOS.Settings.LicenseKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";

            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you do a rebuild and clean and everything?

Comment: Did you update your device?

Comment: @Gerald Versluis Yes several times

Comment: @Taier No, Its been running on ios 9.1

Comment: Make sure you have updates Xamarin, Xcode delete all `bin` and `obj` folders from all the project folders and rebuild.

Comment: @Gerald Versluis I have updated Xamarin nuget package, but still it is not working.

Comment: I would create one more test project in Xamarin.Forms and try to run that project in the same device. If the same issue persists it means the device has some issues. Device log might be helpful in that case. Let me know the outcome.

Comment: @Subhamoy I tried but it is still saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it."

Comment: @ Subhamoy I was using VS2015 for developing my app. I have updated xcode and xamarin studio to latest version in my mac machine. After building the project even the new one it says `The root assembly /Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App13.iOS/d644ae1cb9182dfb1c2fb2b6f7132fa3/bin/iPhone/Debug/App13.iOS.exe conflicts with another assembly (/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App13.iOS/d644ae1cb9182dfb1c2fb2b6f7132fa3/bin/iPhone/Debug/App13.iOS.exe).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this error turned out to be tied to the [Free Provisioning Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=vsmac) and my physical device no longer trusting it. It stopped trusting it immediately after I deleted the application from my phone. I began seeing the error after trying to debug the app again, which reinstalled the app on my phone but failed to launch.

To tell your device to trust the profile again, navigate to `Settings` -> `General` -> `Device Management`. Under the Developer App section, select your provisioning profile, then trust it again.

Within that screen after trusting the app you'll see:

> Apps from developer "iPhone Developer: myProfileName" are trusted on this iPhone and will be trusted until all apps from the developer are deleted.

So, if you ever delete your apps from the physical device, you may run into this again.

I [created a blog post](https://storiknow.com/xamarin-ios-mt1007-failed-to-launch-the-application/) with a bit more detail on how I came to this conclusion.